# ¿Cómo muestra una imagen subida al storage de firebase, en angular 5?

Tags: firebase, angular5, google-cloud-firestore

El código que tengo ya guarda la imagen seleccionada en storage de firebase y en firestore la guardo con el nombre de la imagen, mi problema es cuando consulto la imagen, no puedo mostrarla con 'src', no se como hacer referencia a esa imagen guardada en mi storage.

HTML:

```
           <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Select your image:</label>
            <div class="custom-file">
              <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" (change)="startUpload($event.target.files)">
              <label class="custom-file-label">{{adminJson.fileimg}}</label>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Se ejecuta la función 'startUpload($event.target.files)', que es la siguiente:

```
startUpload(event: FileList){
  this.file = event.item(0)
  console.log('FILE: ', this.file)
   if(this.file.type.split('/')[0] !== 'image'){
     console.error('unsupported file type')
   return
   }
this.fileimg = this.file.name
this.path = `admin/${new Date().getTime()}_${this.file.name}`
this.adminJson.fileimg = this.path // Este string lo guardo en la base de datos
this.task = this.storage.upload(this.path, this.file) //Aquí se guarda en el storage
}
```

Al momento de mostrar la imagen, no sé como hacer referencia a la imagen guardada en mi storage:

```
    <img src="adminJson.fileimg">
```

Comment: agrega tu codigo a tu publicacion.

Comment: Intenta crear un ejemplo de tu problema, o agrega tu código detallando las diferentes cosas que probaste para que puedan ayudarte mejor. Puedes leer [**_¿Como Preguntar?_**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para elaborar mejor la pregunta.

Comment: Ya intenté desenvolver mi problema y añadí mi código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la documentación de angularfire2 encontrarás [un ejemplo que resuelve tu problema](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md#example-usage).

Lo que pasa es que por la manera en que `Storage` trabaja, la dirección en la que guardes tus archivos [u objetos] no es la misma que la dirección para descargarlos. Esa dirección debes obtenerla de firebase con el método `getDownloadUrl()` de la referencia de `Storage`. En tu código se podría aplicar algo así:

```
// ...
this.path = `admin/${new Date().getTime()}_${this.file.name}`;
const fileRef = this.storage.ref( this.path ); // Creamos una referencia para uso posterior
this.task = this.storage.upload(this.path, this.file);
this.task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
            // Cuando finalice la tarea de carga, pedimos la Url
   finalize(() => this.adminJson.fileimg = fileRef.getDownloadUrl() )
)
.subscribe(); // Nos suscribimos a los cambios para que se ejecute
// ...
```

Recuerda que tienes que tener tus reglas de `Storage` en orden para que se pueda descargar a imagen.